# How to unfreeze a user's memory limit?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

For these two days, I have met a weird question.

`STAR` from https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR is a program used to build suffix array indexes. I have been used this program for years. It works OK until recently.

For these days, when I run `STAR`, it will always be killed.

```
root@localhost:STAR --runMode genomeGenerate --runThreadN 10  --limitGenomeGenerateRAM 31800833920 --genomeDir star_GRCh38 --genomeFastaFiles GRCh38.fa --sjdbGTFfile GRCh38.gtf --sjdbOverhang 100
.
.
.
Killed

root@localhost:STAR --runMode genomeGenerate --runThreadN 10 --genomeDir star_GRCh38 --genomeFastaFiles GRCh38.fa --sjdbGTFfile GRCh38.gtf --sjdbOverhang 100
Jun 03 10:15:08 ..... started STAR run
Jun 03 10:15:08 ... starting to generate Genome files
Jun 03 10:17:24 ... starting to sort Suffix Array. This may take a long time...
Jun 03 10:17:51 ... sorting Suffix Array chunks and saving them to disk...
Killed
```

A month ago, the same command with same inputs and same parameters runs OK. It does cost some memory, but not a lot.

I have tried 3 recently released version of this program, all failed. So I do not think it is the question of `STAR` program but my sever configuration.

I also tried to run this program as both `root` and normal user, no lucky for each.

I suspect there is a limitation of memory usage in my server.

But I do not know how the memory is limited? I wonder if some one can give me some hints.

Thanks!

Tong

The following is my debug process and system info.

Command `dmesg -T| grep -E -i -B5 'killed process'` showing it is `Out of memory` problem.

But before the `STAR` program is killed, `top` command showing only `5%` mem is occupied by this porgram.

```
[一 6  1 23:43:00 2020] [40479]  1002 40479   101523    18680     112      487             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[一 6  1 23:43:00 2020] [40480]  1002 40480   101526    18681     112      486             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[一 6  1 23:43:00 2020] [40481]  1002 40481   101529    18682     112      485             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[一 6  1 23:43:00 2020] [40482]  1002 40482   101531    18673     111      493             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[一 6  1 23:43:00 2020] Out of memory: Kill process 33822 (STAR) score 36 or sacrifice child
[一 6  1 23:43:00 2020] Killed process 33822 (STAR) total-vm:23885188kB, anon-rss:10895128kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB

[三 6  3 10:02:13 2020] [12296]  1002 12296   101652    18681     113      486             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[三 6  3 10:02:13 2020] [12330]  1002 12330   101679    18855     112      486             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[三 6  3 10:02:13 2020] [12335]  1002 12335   101688    18682     112      486             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[三 6  3 10:02:13 2020] [12365]  1349 12365    30067     1262      11        0             0 bash
[三 6  3 10:02:13 2020] Out of memory: Kill process 7713 (STAR) score 40 or sacrifice child
[三 6  3 10:02:13 2020] Killed process 7713 (STAR) total-vm:19751792kB, anon-rss:12392428kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
--
[三 6月  3 10:42:17 2020] [ 4697]  1002  4697   101526    18681     112      486             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[三 6月  3 10:42:17 2020] [ 4698]  1002  4698   101529    18682     112      485             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[三 6月  3 10:42:17 2020] [ 4699]  1002  4699   101532    18680     112      487             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[三 6月  3 10:42:17 2020] [ 4701]  1002  4701   101534    18673     110      493             0 /anaconda2/bin/
[三 6月  3 10:42:17 2020] Out of memory: Kill process 21097 (STAR) score 38 or sacrifice child
[三 6月  3 10:42:17 2020] Killed process 21097 (STAR) total-vm:19769500kB, anon-rss:11622928kB, file-rss:884kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Command `free -hl` showing I have enough memory.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G         10G         11G        227G        229G         12G
Low:           251G        240G         11G
High:            0B          0B          0B
Swap:           29G         29G          0B
```

Also as showed by `ulimit -a`, no virtual memory limitation is set.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1030545
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1030545
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Here is the version of my Centos and Kernel (output by `hostnamectl`):

```
hostnamectl
   Static hostname: localhost.localdomain
         Icon name: computer-server
           Chassis: server
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Here shows the content of `cat /etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
* soft nofile 65536
* hard nofile 65536

#@intern    hard    as 162400000
#@intern    hard    nproc 150

# End of file
```

As suggested, I have updated the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem            All  Used  Available (Used)% Mount
devtmpfs             126G     0  126G    0% /dev
tmpfs                126G  1.3M  126G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                126G  4.0G  122G    4% /run
tmpfs                126G     0  126G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cl-root  528G  271G  257G   52% /
/dev/sda1            492M  246M  246M   51% /boot
tmpfs                 26G     0   26G    0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                 26G     0   26G    0% /run/user/1002
tmpfs                 26G     0   26G    0% /run/user/1349
tmpfs                 26G     0   26G    0% /run/user/1855
```

```
ls -a /dev/shm/
.  ..
```

```
grep Shmem /proc/meminfo
Shmem:          238640272 kB
```

Several `tmpfs` costs `126G` memory. I am googleing this, but still not sure what should be done?

That is the problem of shared memory due to program terminated abnormally.

`ipcrm` is used to clear all shared memory and then `STAR running` is fine.

```
$ ipcrm
.....
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           251G         11G        226G        3.9G         14G        235G
Swap:           29G        382M         29G
```

Comment: I suspect you have some temporary storage on tmpfs which uses RAM for temporary files. Any temporary files you create on tmpfs will reduce the amount of RAM available to your system. You have filled SWAP. If you are writing large temporary files, make sure they are not written to tmpfs. Use `mount` to find out what is mounted on tmpfs and you can adjust any temporary files you are using. [tmpfs - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmpfs) is a good cursory reference for managing tmpfs.

Comment: `STAR` from here https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR. I have been used this program for years. It works OK until recently. So I think it may be the problem of my server or server configuration insetead of the program.

Comment: That should go into your question, not in a comment

Comment: Thanks! I have updated to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with shared memory: you have **227G** of memory eaten up by shared objects.

Shared memory files are persistent.  Have a look in `/dev/shm` and any other `tmpfs` mounts to see if there are large files that can be removed to free up more physical memory (RAM+swap).

```sh
$ ls -l /dev/shm
...
$ df -h | grep '^Filesystem\|^tmpfs'
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the output of `df -h`. And after some searching, I am still not sure about the problem. Could you please help to check again?

Comment: @TongChen keep an eye on the `shared` memory over time to see if it grows.  If it does, you'll need to dig more to see which process(es) are responsible.

Comment: Thanks! I am monitering it. I suspect it may be caused by the abnormal termination of `STAR align` programs when using "shared memory" parameters. Suffix array index is loaded to the memory but not released timely. It is my fault, and I will try to work out it.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run a program called STAR, it will always be killed.

**It probably has some [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).** Even old programs may have residual bugs, and they could appear in some very particular cases.

Check with [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) and [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html). Learn also to query `/proc/`, see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [top(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), [htop(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/htop.1.html). See [LinuxAteMyRam](https://linuxatemyram.com/) and read about [memory over-commitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) and [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and perhaps a [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

If you have access to the source code of your `STAR`, consider recompiling it with all warnings and debug info (with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), you would [pass](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-Wall -Wextra -g` to `gcc` or `g++`) then use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) and/or some [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). If you don't have legal access to the source code of `STAR`, contact the entity (person or organization) which provided it to you.

You could be interested in that [draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) and by the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) (or coding your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html#Plugins)).

> So I do not think it is the question of STAR program but my server configuration.

I recommend using `valgrind` or `gdb` and inspect your `/proc/` to validate that optimistic hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for your guides. Sorry I do not express the infos of `STAR` clear. The program may be used by several thousands persons and I have been used it for years.  Normally I would think it is a problem of mine. By the way, thanks for the `Clang static analyzer`. I used to use `valgrind` for my own C programs. Normally it gives lots of fun.